# One parameter subgroup of special Euclidean group

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, matrix-calculus

I am trying to understand the following puzzle, at least for me, in the context of one-parameter subgroups of the Special Euclidean group $\mathbb{SE}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ in n dimensions.

Specifically, I consider $\mathbb{SE}_{n}$ as a subgroup of $\mathbb{GL}_{n+1}(\mathbb{R})$, that is
$$
\mathbb{SE}_{n}(\mathbb{R})=\left\{\left(\matrix{R & v \\ 0 &1}\right) , R\in SO(n), v\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\right\}.
$$
An element in the Lie algebra of $\mathbb{SE}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is then written as
$$
H=\left(\matrix{\Omega & v \\ 0 &0}\right)
$$
where $\Omega$ is a skew-symmetric $(n\times n)$ matrix with real entries.
Then,  the exponential of $H$ can be computed by direct application of the series expansion of the exponential, and it is found to be
$$
\exp(H)=\left(\matrix{\mathrm{e}^{\Omega} & Bv \\ 0 &1}\right).
$$
where
$$
\mathbb{I}_{n} + \sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{\Omega^{k}}{(k+1)!}
$$
$\mathbb{I}_{n}$ being the identity matrix in n dimensions.

At this point, we use the identity
$$
B=\mathbb{I}_{n} + \sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{\Omega^{k}}{(k+1)!}=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{e}^{\lambda\Omega}\mathrm{d}\lambda
$$
and the expression of $\mathrm{e}^{H}\in\mathbb{SE}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is complete.

Now, the puzzle begins.
Suppose we want to compute the one-parameter subgroup generated by $H$.
To do so, and by definition of one-parameter subgroup, we simply have to replace $H$ with $tH$ in the formula above, obtaining
$$
\mathrm{e}^{tH}=\left(\matrix{\mathrm{e}^{t\Omega} & t\,B_{t}v \\ 0 &1}\right)
$$
where
$$
B_{t}=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{e}^{\lambda t\,\Omega}\mathrm{d}\lambda
$$

Let us check the subgroup property, that is, the property
$$
\mathrm{e}^{(t+s)H}=\mathrm{e}^{tH}\,\mathrm{sH}.
$$
The LHS is immediately found to be
$$
\mathrm{e}^{(t+s)H}=\left(\matrix{\mathrm{e}^{(t+s)\Omega} & (t+s)\,B_{t+s}v \\ 0 &1}\right)
$$
with
$$
B_{t+s}=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{e}^{\lambda (t+s)\,\Omega}\mathrm{d}\lambda .
$$
On the other hand, performing the matrix multiplication, the RHS is found to be
$$
\mathrm{e}^{tH}\,\mathrm{e}^{sH}=\left(\matrix{\mathrm{e}^{(t+s)\Omega} & t\,\mathrm{e}^{s H}\,B_{t}v  + s B_{s}v\\ 0 &1}\right).
$$

If the subgroup property holds, as it should be, then we must have
$$
\left(\matrix{\mathrm{e}^{(t+s)\Omega} & (t+s)\,B_{t+s}v \\ 0 &1}\right)=\left(\matrix{\mathrm{e}^{(t+s)\Omega} & t\,\mathrm{e}^{s H}\,B_{t}v  + s B_{s}v\\ 0 &1}\right)
$$
which I am not able to prove.
Furthermore, since $[tH,sH]=0$, we must also have
$$
\mathrm{e}^{sH}\,\mathrm{e}^{tH}=\mathrm{e}^{tH}\,\mathrm{e}^{sH}
$$
which means
$$
\left(\matrix{\mathrm{e}^{(t+s)\Omega} & t\,\mathrm{e}^{s H}\,B_{t}v  + s B_{s}v\\ 0 &1}\right)=\left(\matrix{\mathrm{e}^{(t+s)\Omega} & s\,\mathrm{e}^{t H}\,B_{s}v  + t B_{t}v\\ 0 &1}\right),
$$
and, again, I am not able to prove this statement.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
\begin{align}
\text{LHS}&=\\
te^{s\Omega}\int_0^1e^{\lambda t \Omega}d\lambda+s\int_0^1e^{\lambda s \Omega}d\lambda
&=e^{s\Omega}\int_0^te^{\lambda\Omega}d\lambda+\int_0^se^{\lambda \Omega}d\lambda\\
&=\int_0^te^{(\lambda+s)\Omega}d\lambda+\int_0^se^{\lambda \Omega}d\lambda\\
&=\int_s^{s+t}e^{\lambda\Omega}d\lambda+\int_0^se^{\lambda \Omega}d\lambda\\
&=\int_0^{s+t}e^{\lambda\Omega}d\lambda\\
&=(s+t)\int_0^{1}e^{\lambda(s+t)\Omega}d\lambda\\
&=(s+t)B_{s+t}\\
&=\text{RHS}
\end{align}